# java installation issue

Tags: java

I am not sure what is missing here.  I have installed the java and this is how it looks
`C:\Program Files\Java`
under that folder I have two folders one is `jre` and one is `jdk1.6.0_30`

Now here is what my classpath and also java home looks like

```
 C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system3
 2;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
 \;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program
 Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\maven\3.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem
 \:C:\Users\sgudla\Desktop\jad158g.win;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
**;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\bin**
```

and the java home looks like the following
    **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30**

and the class path looks like the following

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip**;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6
.0_30\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\lib**
```

When I run java in my terminal it gives me the following error

```
C:\>java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

But when I do javac it works fine.  All it has to get is the java.exe file and also javac.exe in the path. I have pointed to jdk bin where the java.exe is.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.  Can some one help me out on this?

Thanks a lot for the answers ..I have just deleted the java.exe file from c:\system\windows 32
that solved the whole issue not sure what was that for though..
Now i am trying to open my eclipse

I am trying to open Eclipse here is what my eclipse.inf file looks like

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Now when i open my eclipse i get the following error
java was started but terminated with exit code 1

Not sure again why it is failing..
Any one has any idea..
Thanks,
Swati

Comment: Try to use `java -version` and `javac -version` in your command prompt and see if they are returning your correct versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [what](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/) google gave me: try to remove `java.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: i have removed the c:\Windows\System32 the java.exe file it works fine now...thx a lot

Comment: Now i am trying to open my eclipse i am getting the following error

Comment: try to remove everything from c:\Windows\System32 starting with java and reinstall java

Answer (score 1):

Try the same command "java" from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin

If the same problem exists, it's an installation problem.

If not, it's a path problem.

Comment: It can't be a path problem, because `java.exe` is executed. The thing is that it can't find the class `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Please update the original question with additional info instead of adding it comments

Comment: Yea now i have modified the question